# Handling URIError: URI malformed with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, uri, vue-router

I came across a negative scenario in my website where someone appends `%` at the end of a URL and we are getting `URIError: URI malformed` in this case. Sometimes, the page stops rendering with this. I am using Vue-Router for routing, and I tried `router.beforeResolve` and `router.beforeEach` methods but they are not getting called. I want to do something like this to fix the problem:

```
try {
   decodeURI(uri)
   next();
} catch(e) {
   // If malformed URI error, don't go to URI, else next();
}
```

The confusion is where do I put this code? Which Vue router method will get called in this case?
Router code is similar to this one:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        ARoute,
        BRoute,
    ],
});
```

Comment: What do you expect vue-router to do when someone appends % at the end of the url?

Comment: @lukaszmtw  I don't have much knowledge about vue-router, but I want to handle this scenario somewhat gracefully, by redirecting to 404 page or at least catching this error somewhere so the page won't freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much you can do about it without modifying the `vue-router` code, as the decoding is happening there. [This issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2725) on vue-router's Github repo might be related to it.